# Как добавить дропдаун элемент в sidenav на angular 6?

Tags: angular

Есть меню https://stackblitz.com/edit/responsive-menu-angular-material-flex-layout?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html
И мне надо там у Menu Item 2 добавить выпадающие элементы, как это сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Предлагаю добавить выпадающее меню таким образом

```
<a href="#" mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">Menu Item 2</a>
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
  <button mat-menu-item>
    <mat-icon>dialpad</mat-icon>
    <span>Redial</span>
  </button>
  <button mat-menu-item disabled>
    <mat-icon>voicemail</mat-icon>
    <span>Check voicemail</span>
  </button>
  <button mat-menu-item>
    <mat-icon>notifications_off</mat-icon>
    <span>Disable alerts</span>
  </button>
</mat-menu>
```

В `app.module.ts` добавить MatMenuModule

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { MatToolbarModule, MatSidenavModule, MatListModule, MatButtonModule, MatIconModule, MatMenuModule } from "@angular/material";
import { FlexLayoutModule } from "@angular/flex-layout";

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatListModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    FlexLayoutModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

[Пример](https://stackblitz.com/edit/responsive-menu-angular-material-flex-layout-dvnx7j)